# Cards that have same fields to have hame height for each field

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to generate cards, each card has some fields, between all the cards, they all have the same fields, but different data, for example, one card may look like this:

```
<h3> Card Name 1</h3>
<p> name: Andrew </p>
<p> age: 23 </p>
<p> motto: You only live once </p>
```

and another card might look like this:

```
<h3> Card Name 2</h3>
<p> name: Tristan </p>
<p> age: 27 </p>
<p> motto: yolo </p>
```

And I want to display the cards side by side, with the content rendered in a column for each card.

The problem, a field might have different heights, for example first motto might need 2 rows, while the second motto, might need only 1 row.

How can I force the styling in this way that for each field, all cards have the maximum needed height, in order to be easy to check the values?

I have to mention that there can be more than 2 cards

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/QWgwEeG

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a flex box as shown in the example below. Here, the property `flex: 1` additionally ensures the cards are of equal width. Alternatively, manually specify a card width by replacing it with `width: 250px`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.card {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Card Name 1</h3>
    <p>name: Andrew</p>
    <p>age: 23</p>
    <p>motto: You only live once</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Card Name 2</h3>
    <p>name: Tristan</p>
    <p>age: 27</p>
    <p>motto: yolo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Card Name 3</h3>
    <p>name: Tristan</p>
    <p>age: 27</p>
    <p>
      motto: yolo<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Quia debitis voluptatibus dolorem dolore expedita veniam sint
      neque minima. Tempora quisquam vero aliquid earum odio autem corporis
      nobis. Sint, repudiandae quia!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But my problem is more like: if we add another field after the motto, it will be on different position in the card, depending on how long the motto was

Comment: @shalamel_bartalogonos If the lengths of the field values are unknown, I suggest using a [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) instead. You can then use CSS to make the columns look like cards.